# Error with treating dates, lubridate package in R

Tags: r, date, lubridate

Hey look what I found out.

Reading [link](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/dates-and-times.html#creating-datetimes), 16.2.1, I tried the followings.

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
> mdy("January 31st, 2017")
[1] "2017-03-01"
> mdy("January 29th, 2017")
[1] "2017-02-09"
```

What is wrong here?

The following works quite good, so I don't think locale thing is the problem..?

```
> mdy("January 1st, 2017")
[1] "2017-01-01"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not able to reproduce the issue with `packageVersion` `1.7.4`

```
library(lubridate) # v 1.7.4
mdy("January 31st, 2017")
#[1] "2017-01-31" 
mdy("January 29th, 2017")
#[1] "2017-01-29"
```

Comment: hmm, funny. Maybe locale is the real problem here. Can you answer me where your locale is by using `Sys.getlocale()` or something?

Comment: @HyeonPhilYoun  I get `"en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8"`